# Engraving Logo onto Pill

Tags: modeling

Can somebody help me turn my model to look more pill like? I need to smoothen out pretty much all the hard edges now but when I click shade smooth it turns into a mess. I am trying to engrave/deboss a logo onto a pill.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=oMxkWmq5" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/oMxkWmq5/)

Answer (score 1):

Right click > *Shade Smooth*, then in the *Object Data panel > Clear Custom Split Normals Data*, then *Auto Smooth*:

[image]

Here it what it gives, if you want a rounder object you'll need to create some bevels manually and give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

[image]

Comment: Yes this mostly helped, I am going to restart and add more geometry to the pill + circle engraving. Should be much better along with your solution. Thank you moon boots

Comment: I would also recommend you to use a SubD modifier and a bevel modifier to achieve more realism.

Comment: @Evripidis Lalissidis Sure, that's what I say in my answer, but it would need a bit of work around the letters

Comment: If you apply the Scale it works

Comment: Oh ok I couldn't make it work, I must miss something